# running NSTimer or UILocalNotification in background

Tags: ios, background, nstimer, uilocalnotification

How can I perform a count down Timer on iOS?

Firstly, I tried `NSTimer`. Then I found `NSTimer` could not work when app enter into background.

Second,  I used

```
counterTask = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]
              beg
inBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
              }];
```

to let the  `NSTimer` work on background. But then I found iOS just allow the app work on background no more than 600s (10 mins). I can not figure out how to let `NSTimer` more than 10 min in background.

Third, I tired to use `NSLocalNotification`, and it works well. But the thing I wanna do is to pause the playing music by calling a method. I found the `UILocalNotification` will show a alert when it is the time. If you did not click the alert button, the method - `(void)application:(UIApplication *)app didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification` will not called. I don't know how to call a method without click the alert button.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification {
    NSLog(@"Recieved Notification %@",notification);
    UIAlertView *alert=[[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Local Notification" message:@"message"
                              delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil
                    otherButtonTitles:nil, nil] autorelease];
   [alert show];
}
```

So, the question is
1. How to let the `NSTimer` run in background more than 10 mins,
or
2. How to call my own method without click the alert button when it is the time for `UILocalNotification`.

Thanks so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
counterTask = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]
          beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
          }];
```

Put something in the expiration handler that will make another timer which has another expiration handler that makes another timer that has another handler that makes...